# graph image size disturbed, probably by canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, vis.js, pyvis

I have a node graph generated by PyVis and saved as a HTML file. I also have set width to 100% and height to 95%.

The source code has no 'canvas' element/tag mentioned specifically.

Opening the file in a browser, for some reason the graph image doesn't fit to height of 95%. Upon inspecting the image element, i then see a 'canvas' element gets into the code and it is messing up the graph size. From the inspect tool, disabling element.style height and width will get the graph size that I had defined. I am not sure how to overcome this in the code.

I need to be able to resize the image to the size i wish for to present the data in a better way, please help. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks heaps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample Graph</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vis-network@latest/styles/vis-network.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vis-network@latest/dist/vis-network.js"> </script>

    <style type="text/css">

            #mynetwork {
                width: 100%;
                height: 95%;
                background-color: #eeeeee;
                border: 1px solid lightgray;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
            }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Sample Graph</h2>

<div id = "mynetwork"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // initialize global variables.
    var edges;
    var nodes;
    var network;
    var container;
    var options, data;


    // This method is responsible for drawing the graph, returns the drawn network
    function drawGraph() {
        var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');



        // parsing and collecting nodes and edges from the python
        nodes = new vis.DataSet([
            {"color": "mediumslateblue", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node A", "image": "", "label": "node A", "level": 1, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode A\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"},
            {"color": "plum", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 50}, "group": "group_others", "id": "node M3ca", "image": "", "label": "node M3ca", "level": 3, "shape": "ellipse", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode M3ca\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"},
            {"color": "slategrey", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node 3", "image": "", "label": "node 3", "level": 3, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "some_title"},
            {"color": "mediumslateblue", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node B", "image": "", "label": "node B", "level": 3, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode B\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"},
            {"color": "mediumslateblue", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node 1c", "image": "", "label": "node 1c", "level": 3, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode 1c\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"}
        ]);
        edges = new vis.DataSet([
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "Olive", "dashes": false, "from": "node A", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {}, "title": "node A\u003ci\u003e[7]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node M3ca\u003ci\u003e[1]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node M3ca", "weight": 1},
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "ForestGreen", "dashes": false, "from": "node A", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {}, "title": "node A\u003ci\u003e[10]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node 3\u003ci\u003e[10]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node 3", "weight": 1},
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "IndianRed", "dashes": false, "from": "node A", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {"type": "dynamic"}, "title": "node A\u003ci\u003e[19]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node B\u003ci\u003e[19]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node B", "weight": 1},
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "YellowGreen", "dashes": false, "from": "node 1c", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {}, "title": "node 1c\u003ci\u003e[43]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node A\u003ci\u003e[3]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node A", "weight": 1}
        ]);

        // adding nodes and edges to the graph
        data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};

        var options = {"configure": {"enabled": false}, "edges": {"color": {"inherit": true}, "smooth": {"enabled": true, "type": "dynamic"}, "hoverWidth": 10, "selectionWidth": 15, "width": 5}, "interaction": {"dragNodes": true, "hideEdgesOnDrag": false, "hideNodesOnDrag": false, "hover": true, "multiselect": true}, "physics": {"barnesHut": {"avoidOverlap": 0.25, "centralGravity": 0, "damping": 0.09, "gravitationalConstant": -20000, "springConstant": 0.001, "springLength": 95}, "enabled": true, "stabilization": {"enabled": true, "fit": true, "iterations": 1000, "onlyDynamicEdges": false, "updateInterval": 50}}};





        network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);






        return network;

    }

    drawGraph();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output that i see in my browser.
[![Actual image rendered in the browser][1]][1]

And here is what i am expecting to see in my browser.
[![Expected Image to be rendered in the browser][2]][2]

Further, after the result is shown on the browser, i right click ont he html page and view the page source-code and i see the code as below.
Node the new addition of  element to my original source code, i never made that addition, i believe that was added by java script to draw canvas image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Network Graph Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/latest/vis.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/latest/vis-network.min.js"> </script>

    <style type="text/css">
            #mynetwork {
                width: 100%;
                height: 95%;
                background-color: #eeeeee;
                border: 1px solid lightgray;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
            }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/custom/my.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/custom/my.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Network Graph Homepage</h1> 

<div id="mynetwork"><div class="vis-network" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; touch-action: pan-y; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><canvas width="1856" height="151" style="position: relative; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas></div></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    // initialize global variables.
    var edges;
    var nodes;
    var network;
    var container;
    var options, data;


    // This method is responsible for drawing the graph, returns the drawn network
    function drawGraph() {
        var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');



        // parsing and collecting nodes and edges from the python
        nodes = new vis.DataSet([
            {"color": "mediumslateblue", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node A", "image": "", "label": "node A", "level": 1, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode A\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"},
            {"color": "plum", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 50}, "group": "group_others", "id": "node M3ca", "image": "", "label": "node M3ca", "level": 3, "shape": "ellipse", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode M3ca\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"},
            {"color": "slategrey", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node 3", "image": "", "label": "node 3", "level": 3, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "some_title"},
            {"color": "mediumslateblue", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node B", "image": "", "label": "node B", "level": 3, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode B\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"},
            {"color": "mediumslateblue", "font": {"color": "black", "face": "Verdana", "size": 100}, "group": "grwy", "id": "node 1c", "image": "", "label": "node 1c", "level": 3, "shape": "circle", "size": 10, "title": "\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003enode 1c\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e"}
        ]);
        edges = new vis.DataSet([
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "Olive", "dashes": false, "from": "node A", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {}, "title": "node A\u003ci\u003e[7]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node M3ca\u003ci\u003e[1]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node M3ca", "weight": 1},
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "ForestGreen", "dashes": false, "from": "node A", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {}, "title": "node A\u003ci\u003e[10]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node 3\u003ci\u003e[10]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node 3", "weight": 1},
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "IndianRed", "dashes": false, "from": "node A", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {"type": "dynamic"}, "title": "node A\u003ci\u003e[19]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node B\u003ci\u003e[19]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node B", "weight": 1},
            {"arrows": {"to": {"enabled": false}}, "color": "YellowGreen", "dashes": false, "from": "node 1c", "label": 1, "length": 1000, "smooth": {}, "title": "node 1c\u003ci\u003e[43]\u003c/i\u003e   \u003c-----\u003e   node A\u003ci\u003e[3]\u003c/i\u003e", "to": "node A", "weight": 1}
        ]);

        // adding nodes and edges to the graph
        data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};

        var options = {"configure": {"enabled": false}, "edges": {"color": {"inherit": true}, "smooth": {"enabled": true, "type": "dynamic"}, "hoverWidth": 10, "selectionWidth": 15, "width": 5}, "interaction": {"dragNodes": true, "hideEdgesOnDrag": false, "hideNodesOnDrag": false, "hover": true, "multiselect": true}, "physics": {"barnesHut": {"avoidOverlap": 0.25, "centralGravity": 0, "damping": 0.09, "gravitationalConstant": -20000, "springConstant": 0.001, "springLength": 95}, "enabled": true, "stabilization": {"enabled": true, "fit": true, "iterations": 1000, "onlyDynamicEdges": false, "updateInterval": 50}}};





        network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);






        return network;

    }

    drawGraph();

</script>


</body>
</html>

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxF6v.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQGeC.jpg
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the 'canvas messing up...'. The canvas is where the graph has been drawn. Could you explain a bit what the 95% is to be a percentage of?

Comment: Hi @AHaworth, I just added screenshots showing a little more understanding, thanks for your time, please help me further.
The first image is what is rendered on the browser, whereas 2nd image is what i expect to see.

I also wonder how to have my html source code to change image size of the canvas that was written by the JavaScript. Please help me out further. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got same problem and i easly fix it by change height from '%' to 'vw', so do like this in style

```
<style type="text/css">

    #mynetwork {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vw;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

this method works for me all time

Comment: Thanks heaps @SamilYT , that worked like charm ^_^